# SharePoint 2007: Filter for current year

Tags: list, list-view, filter

I have a list view web part and a field named [Year] set as a number. I am trying to filter to show this current year's items, given today's date. I tried the following filter but get `Filter value is not a number`:

```
YEAR([Today])
```

I am using SharePoint 2007 Standard.

Comment: could you provide a little more code to help you out?

Answer (score 1):

One option we've used in the past is to create a calculated field in the list for the Year that is usually something like `YEAR([Created])` and then create filters against that field.  We have documented bugs with Microsoft on a few places where filters and grouping fails when trying to use a formula for date conversion and it is possible you are hitting one of those.

Comment: I can't used the created field because the items were not added in order. That's why I added the year field.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a filter for that. Have you tried to create a new column called Filter Year or something like that. Make this a calculated list. And use the formulabox to filter by year (do you want this year, or maybe Create - 365) and choose the Date and Time format and
Date Only. Then setting it up on a new view.

Not sure if this is what you wanted, or if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Today function cannot be used to extract the current year on the fly for a filter value.  You could create a view that is grouped by the year column, so the user can simply expand or collapse a specific year. Or, instead of a list view web part, use a data view web part and set the filter in SharePoint Designer.